# Redis - how to load CSV into a table?

Tags: redis, key

Is it possible to load CSV file directly into Redis (5.X) or CSV first needs to be converted into JSON and then load it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to store the data in your CSV file, you may or may not need to process it programmatically. For example, running this:

```
redis-cli SET foo "$(cat myfile.csv)"
```

will result with the contents of the files stored in the key 'foo' as a Redis String. If you want to store each line in its own data structure under a key (perhaps a Hash with all the columns), you'll need to process it with code and populate the database accordingly.

Note: there is no need, however, to convert it to JSON.